# I am having trouble installing steam and other applications

Tags: steam

When I install steam on ubuntu it works then at the end of the steam installation process it gives me the error message missing the following 32 bit libraries: libgl.so.1 the closes. How can i fix this? There is no information on the steam support page to help.
I fixed the initial problem but now i am missing new libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using nvidia and  have installed nvidia driver, if not please refer to respective instruction how to install it on your machine. try the following:

1. add arcitechture i386 `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`
2. assuming you have installed nvidia or any graphic driver, you need to reinstall it
3. restart or logout login, then it should work

Comment: That isnt doing anything in the terminal. Also i ave had trouble installing the nvidia driver.

Comment: that didnt fix it

Comment: what kind of problem? and are you using nvidia?